# Having trouble installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I know it has been asked before but I had trouble relating to my options during my installation so I felt the need to ask again. I'm on a Windows 8.1 pre-installed laptop that has been upgraded to Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu as dual-boot. I've already partitioned my drive for Ubuntu and I got to the installation screen. I had no issues until I had to choose my boot load installation. I had no idea what to choose and I need your guidance since I'm new to this. I'll post some screen-shots down below.

[image]
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best practice would be install GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader) at the very beginning of the hard-disk (in the root of hdd), usually meaning `/dev/sda/`. Your particular case is a little different: you have two (or more) hard-disks united by RAID technology. That's why they appear as one device called `dev/sdd`. And that's why the long names and common mounting directory under `/dev/mapper/`. Partitions are no longer mapped ('linked') to a physical disk, but to a RAID disk. Therefore, i would install GRUB under `/dev/sdd/` , meaning the root of the RAID disk.

Comment: @ipselute Thank you for the answer! I have both an SSD drive (my C) and an HDD (my D drive). I'm kind of confused as to which one I should install on since I'm a complete newbie on linux/ubuntu. Also, does it matter on which disk my partition should be on? Thanks in advance! Edit: I also have files on my D drive (my HDD) which I don't want to lose access to from my Windows.

Comment: As you can see, there are more Windows partitions than C and D. In Win10 there are a couple more Win-related partitions (microsoft-reserved, recovery, sometimes an OEM partition). Beside that there is an EFI partition (required on every EFI hardware). When you have a RAID unification, the SSD and the HDD space become one contiguous storage space. You can have a partition spanning from second half of SSD all the way to the first half of HDD (for example). Associating partitions to physical hardware is no longer relevant when using RAID.

Comment: Before installing Ubuntu, boot it in Live mode, open GParted and check the partition map. Don't delete EFI, ms-reserved and recovery partitions. Also find out what partition your Windows is installed (make sure you don't delete that either). Make a screenshot of GParted and put it in your question cause a can't tell which one is it. You could shrink your D drive, and create a swap and an ext partitions for your Ubuntu. It should make sense to install Ubuntu after Windows partition (for not moving Win). EFI(ESP) partition MUST always be first partition.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me install 16.04 on my msi CX61 2PC with Windows 10 installed:
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)